# MSDN Subscriptions = Windows 7 Ultimate License?

Tags: windows, license, license-key, msdn

If I were to get a [MSDN Operating Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/buy.aspx) license, would that also mean I would have access to download the Windows 7 ISO, along with Windows Vista, and XP? Can anyone with access to MSDN show us all what kind of privileged it grants you?

I'm asking because I need a Windows 7 License myself, I want to get Ultimate, and I will soon. But I also help a lot of friends with their computers, and I find myself in need of access to different versions of windows install media. Would getting an MSDN subscription offer me that benefit? Could I download the XP, Vista, or 7 ISO files if I needed to and just use their Serial Number to re-install their OS for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to be clear: MSDN is not licensed for you to let all your friends install using the keys you would get, but yes, you have access to a great range of ISO's to re-install using their keys.

You would have access to virtually every OS, every version, going back to DOS, except for ones (95/98/ME) excluded by a settlement over Microsoft's virtual machine (Java settlement).

Also, although the activations never expire, technically, you are supposed to renew your subscription yearly to keep using the software.

This is not MSDN, but TechNet. This is VERY similar to MSDN, except that MSDN has virtually every language under the sun. There may be some other difference that I am not aware of, but based on the sample screenshots, I suspect that you will be well-served by TechNet alone. One other benefit other than it is only about $325 ($250 renewal), so much cheaper than MSDN, is that you also get two Microsoft Support cases yearly. So you can call them for support at no cost twice (regularly $260 per call, so worth it for this alone).

These are sample screenshots of the download pages, which are very similar for MSDN. Note the all editions for the OS, and Office. This is one of my greatest tools for learning.

[image] 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Tell me what you want MSDN for, because you might be better off with the cheaper TechNet, which may still have everything you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I **explicitly** said their keys. I'm not looking to do anything illegal, I just want to help some friends out, and if I can also get a Windows 7 License out of the deal, I'm all for it. So does that mean, that I get a Windows 7 License for myself? Will it be a full copy? Are there any restrictions on MSDN versions of Windows?

Comment: I know you did...I was just making it clear to ANYONE, who reads the answer.

Comment: There are no restrictions on the installs, and as I mentioned. they do not die. To legally continue using them, you are supposed to renew yearly, that is a major difference though.

Comment: I pretty much just want access to the Official Windows ISO files directly from Microsoft. If I can also get a Windows 7 License for myself at a reduced cost or free (as it would be included in the price of the TechNet or MSDN licensing then I would be happy to go do that.)

Comment: Cool thanks. I'm not to thrilled about the idea of having to `rent` a windows license. Even if it is a annual payment, $699 up front, then $499 for the MSDN version is not very good.

Comment: You are indeed renting it, but depending on what you do with it, it can still be worth it. At least with the option I just gave you, you save about 50%, get the two cases, and still get what you want (I think).

Comment: I think I will go with `TechNet`, thank you.

Comment: I figured that would work for you. ONe last thing: I said $325 because that is what it costs from retailers. It is $349 from Microsoft directly, but you get immediate access.

Comment: Glad I could help, and thank you for marking it. I hope you liked the screenshots. :)

Comment: I did, the screen shots where very helpful.

Comment: OH, one more thing: There is no limit on the installs. I have a HUGE collection of VM's running Windows 7 /Server 2008, and there is no limit to the number of times you can activate them.

Comment: @KCotreau: Regarding the VM licensing, does MS explicitly say this is alright?  I am an embedded SW engineer looking to create several VM's legally for special tool chains.  I am using Win 7's XP Mode right now with limited success.

Comment: @Adam Lewis There is no such thing as VM licensing. These subscriptions are only for testing and cannot be used in production, and they do allow multiple installs. I almost never come here any more, so if you have further questions, call Microsoft and ask them to clarify their licensing.